# What does $Pa(u^{(i)})$ notation mean?

Tags: notation, machine-learning

I'm reading the deep-learning book and this expression comes up, and I'm pretty sure it hasn't been described earlier, it's not in the glossary and I can't find it used in google.

This is the algorithm, it's a graph description of a neural net, and it is used to describe backpropagation.

[image]

Comment: I guess its parent (node).

Comment: Wouldn't that just be  $u^{(i-1)}$ ?

Comment: No, I think that $u^{(j)}$ is a parent node of $u^{(i)}$. By topological sorting, $j<i$.